# Screen flashing on install

Tags: flash, screen

im trying to install Ubuntu but when i boot and try to install from USB DVD drive the screen is flashing i can just about make out what it is asking me and i can install but even after boot up the install is tillflashing the screen on and off

i am installing it on a HP rove as listed here
http://store.hp.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/PDPStdView?catalogId=10051&productId=503070&storeId=10151

any one any ideas as to me it looks like a graphic driver problem

and it isn't just this OS it did it with open suse aswell

Comment: Does it do the same thing when booting from the original OS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried [Ubuntu's advanced boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)?

When booting the DVD, press any key when the keyboard and the little guy are on the bottom of the screen.

Especially note the function key <kbd>F4</kbd> modes:

I would start trying the following video modes:

1. 771 (800x600)
2. 775 (1280×1024)

All of the video modes for Linux are in this excellent [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers)

Once you've got everything up and running, *and can see what you're doing* you can then try to go to "additional drivers" in the dash and download video drivers that better fit your 1600x900 screen.

Comment: i managed to get it to boot steady and the screen is stable. but the video driver i can not find for intel HD 4400. i have found a few but nothing will install or change the video driver from the default

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have your hardware, so I cannot test this (you're always welcome to send me an additional machine! ;) ) but I found a driver from 11 Nov 2014:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Comment: thanks i will try it out monday i left the machine in the office on friday i couldn't be bothered messing around with it ... so i brought the mac home ....

Comment: @MikeJAspinall I realize it's been quite a long time since your post, but I'm having the same screen flashing problem on booting Ubuntu.  I'm wondering how you managed to get "the boot steady" ?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dharamija: Have you tried the solution in the answer? (try 771 first)

Comment: @MikeJAspinall thanks for the follow up.  Turns out I used the wrong distro on the install.  I installed the 64bit Trusty instead of the 32bit.